# Detect media capture on hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, event-handling, capture, hololens

I need to detect if the Hololens captures a photo or a video, in order to start some post-processing steps.

I tried using AppCapture.GetForCurrentView().CapturingChanged as suggested in [this post](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/1402/is-there-any-way-to-detect-recording-is-going-on), but it doesn't work. The event listener method is never called.

Is there are way to get the volume button presses in Unity? That way I could at least "assume" that a photo or video has been taken.

The other option would be to check the Camera Roll folder for new files all the time, and do something if a new file appears. But that doesn't feel really elegant or efficient.

Best regards,
Wavy

Comment: are u taking the photo and if yes, how?

Comment: We use Unity's [PhotoCapture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.WebCam.PhotoCapture.html) and it works fine

Comment: I'm using the physical volume buttons on the Hololens. I don't want or need to include an extra virtual button to take a screenshot.